# iPhone supported orientations in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, orientation

I've set in plist that it should only support portrait mode, but when I rotate it the view changes. It worked for me before, but not now...

Please help, it's driving me crazy!

Comment: What does the plist say, what have you tried?  More info required.

Comment: Supported interface orientations:
Item 0           Portrait (bottom home button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vedran Burojević,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
```

}

the above code only support portrait mode..

Answer (score 0):

you can write the code in this.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) 
}
```